# Search and replace the first delimiter in each line for large file?

Tags: regex, windows, text

I have some large files (bigger than 2GB ), and the text in the files has the following format:

```
2013/4/18;22:5:42.668;13266;10;13279;10
2013/4/18;22:10:48.820;13271;10;13279;10
2013/4/18;22:12:0.956;13266;10;13279;10
2013/4/18;22:12:44.826;13266;10;13284;10
...
```

I would like to accomplish the following task

```
- replace the 1st semi-colon ";" in each line to space character " "
- replace the rest semi-colon ";" in each line to comma character ","
```

The output should look like as below

```
2013/4/18 22:5:42.668,13266,10,13279,10
2013/4/18 22:10:48.820,13271,10,13279,10
2013/4/18 22:12:0.956,13266,10,13279,10
2013/4/18 22:12:44.826,13266,10,13284,10
...
```

Can any one please advise me how to ?

Comment: Do you have emacs? It is very easy in emacs

Comment: `sed -e 's/;/ /' -e 's/;/,/g'` if you have `sed`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler does windows have `sed`?

Comment: @Nullpointer I just download emac, can you show me what to do

Comment: @Nullpointer: Cygwin on Windows does; so does MinGW.  But they're not standard on Windows, hence the 'if' in my comment (and its comment status, not answer status).  If you've got a Unix-derived editor, then you could use the two substitute commands globally over the file (`:g/;/s/;/ /` and `:g/;/s/;/,/g` in `vim`, for example; it'll be possible in `emacs` too, but I don't know the syntax).  I don't know how you'd do it neatly with just Windows tools; there's probably a way, but ...

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not a regex this will do your work!
This is called emacs keyborad macro!

These are the keys you need to press after opening this file in emacs.

Why I am asking you to define you the macro is because once defined you can use it anytime for any file by just pressing one or two keys.

Open your file in emacs and start pressing these keys:

```
alt-shift-, //go to the start of the file
ctrl-x-(    //start defining keyboard macro
ctrl-s      //search for some thing
;           //that something is your ;
ctrl-b      //move one step back
ctrl-d      //delete the ;
[space-bar] //add space
ctrl-[space-bar] //start selecting region
ctrl-e      //select region till the end of line
alt-shift-5 //replace all from region
;           //replace ; 
,           //with ,
shift-1     //do this for all ; in region
ctrl-e      //move to end of line
ctrl-f      //go to start of next line
ctrl-x-)    //end macro
//now-your-macro-is-defined
ctrl-[space-bar] //again define the region
alt-shift-.     //select all file (except first line)
M-x-apply-macro-to-region //apply perviously defined macro to complete file!
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily in [gVim for Windows](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc). First, we replace the 1st semi-colon in each line with space by a simple [macro](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros). To enter the macro, type:

```
ggq1(or any letter)^f;r jq
```

explanation:

- `gg`: go to the start of the file
- `q1`: start recording to register 1 or anywhere
- `^`: go to the start of a line
- `f;`: go to the occurrence of `;` to the right
- `r`: replace the character under the cursor with space
- `j`: go to next line
- `q`: stop recording

then execute the macro from the second line by type `:2,$:normal @1` in command mode, now the 1st semi-colons of all lines are replaced by a space. After that, use `:%s/;/,/g` to replace the rest semi-colons.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perl one liner that does the job:

```
perl -api.back -e 's/;/ /; s/;/,/g;' in.txt
```

The original file is save under `in.txt.back` and the replacement is done in-place.